# Installing a package on Linux absent .deb or configuration files

Tags: 18.04, apt, software-installation, dpkg

I'm trying to install a primarily Window-based package from github [here](https://github.com/plotly/falcon/releases/tag/v4.1.0).

They do offer a linux-specific download, but unpacking the tarball, I don't see any configure or make files that would allow me to build from source.  Attempting to run the included .exe file also gives an error:

```
chris@chris-x1c6:~/Desktop/falcon-sql-client-4.1.0$ ./falcon-sql-client 
./falcon-sql-client: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Documentation is similarly [sparse](https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/database-connectors/personal-login/).  Any other thoughts on how to install this?

**Edit:**

As the package is apparently no longer maintained, and a deb file wasn't available, I installed the missing library:

`sudo apt install libgconf2-4`

Am able to launch the package successfully using `./falcon-sql-client` now.

Thanks for the input, guys.

Comment: There is no INSTALL or README file?

Comment: @user535733, there's a README, but it doesn't say anything about linux installation:  https://github.com/plotly/falcon/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is [this](https://appimage.github.io/falcon-sql-client/) of any help?

Comment: @AndyJ, sort of.  I'd seen AppImages used for linux installs from prior versions (thought 4.1 doesn't include one).  Going through the versions list it looks like prior versions included both deb packages and AppImage files (eg, https://github.com/plotly/falcon/releases/tag/v3.0.3).  Wonder if they simply didn't upload them for later versions, or if there's a way to create the .deb file from what they did include for linux.

Comment: Saw your query in git https://github.com/plotly/falcon/issues/571 and, well, you've done all you can until the author responds.

Comment: @K7AAY, :) yup.  Just sent the maintainer an email asking to up a deb file.  Hopefully speeds things up.

Comment: Hmm, looks like they're no longer maintaining the product.  Might need to install an older version unless there's a way to create a .deb file from the content they've included (never created one myself).

Comment: The error message complains about a missing library, `libgconf-2.so.4`. See if a package provides it: `dpkg -S libgconf-2.so.4`. Install that package.

Comment: @waltinator, good idea. `sudo apt install libgconf2-4` installed the missing library; able to launch the program successfully using `./falcon-sql-client` now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside your question.